# Changing layer name in QGIS by replacing only a part of it using Python

Tags: pyqgis, layers, replace

I want to change only a part of a layer name in QGIS. The original layer names are of the form "2d_mat_Luton_developed", "2d_mat_Luton_exist", etc. with different suffixes and I want to change them to "Mannings Roughness_developed", "Mannings Roughness_exist", etc..
I tried the following code in the Python console, but it is not working/nothing is changing.

```
    from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

for layer in layers:
    if '2d_mat' in layer.name():
        layer.name.replace('2d_mat_Luton','Mannings Roughness')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do `'string'.replace('st', 'ST')` insdead of setting the actual layer name.

Use `layer.setName` to set it propperly.

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.setName

Try this code:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if 'layer' in layer.name():
        name = layer.name()
        new_name = name.replace('scratch','SCRATCH')
        layer.setName(new_name)
```

[image]

Comment: I have many layers to replace name and its not efficient to type them all. I know setName, but not finding efficient here.

Comment: Getting this error, AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'. How to import this replace function?

Comment: @K.M.Muha See update.